# Should firebase auth onCreate trigger have more data?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm using `functions.auth.user().onCreate()` as part of a firestore project, and trying to set up some default data when a new user registers. For the front end, I'm using firebase-ui, with Google and Email/Password providers enabled.

When I sign in with an email and password, the UI widget prompts to enter a name and set a password. I was expecting to see the name as part of the `user` parameter in the `onCreate()` function call, but I'm getting practically nothing:

```
user: { email: 'xxx@yyyy.co.uk',
  emailVerified: false,
  displayName: null,
  photoURL: null,
  phoneNumber: null,
  disabled: false,
  providerData: [],
  customClaims: {},
  passwordSalt: null,
  passwordHash: null,
  tokensValidAfterTime: null,
  metadata: 
   UserRecordMetadata {
     creationTime: '2018-11-20T15:06:01Z',
     lastSignInTime: '2018-11-20T15:06:01Z' },
  uid: 'QDJ5OJTwbvNo2QNDVQV9VsxC2pz2',
  toJSON: [Function] }
```

Not even getting the provider info so I can tell which 'kind' of user registered. It's almost like this function is triggered before the user record has been populated (except the email address *does* get through). Also, registrations via the Google provider come with a fully-populated `user` record, so I guess this is a problem with Email/Password specifically.

Is this a bug, or am I missing something? I didn't see anything else useful in the `context` parameter either.

Comment: I think it's a slightly different scenario, since my client-side code isn't actually creating the account, and the user doesn't have write access to the firestore collection I want to update (hence using a triggered cloud function). But, are you saying that the prompt 'First & last name' when using firebase-ui is never made available to the triggered function?

Comment: The fact that `displayName` is not populated in the Cloud Functions `onCreate` trigger for email+password is expected. The function is triggered from the first API call, while the display name is set with a second API call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that `displayName` is not populated in the Cloud Functions `onCreate` trigger for email+password is expected. The function is triggered from the first API call (`createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`), while the display name is set with a second API call (`updateProfile`).

The usual workaround would be to create a Cloud Function to update the user profile, as shown here: [Firebase Auth+Functions | create user with displayName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48741932/firebase-authfunctions-create-user-with-displayname/48742467#comment93672763_48742467)

I also highly recommend [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) to be able to have a Cloud Function triggered on profile changes.

Comment: Thanks Frank. Is it firebase-ui making that second API call to `updateProfile` when email/password is the login method? Or does that need to be explicitly done in the client?

Comment: I think FirebaseUI does that for you.

Comment: Thanks—feature request submitted. I also suggested maybe extending `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` to allow additional, optional, data such as `displayName`, so that the existing `onCreate()` trigger could receive a more fully-populated `UserInfo` record. That would suit my needs in this case just as well. Tx.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have a `onCreate` hook creating the user in the DB. I have to create a post creation function to update the user data in the db. Should I even have the `onCreate` hook? is it better to just have everything in a single post-creation function? I'm worried the onCreate won't trigger fast enough and the post-creation function will find no user created in the DB.

Comment: Yeah, I'd definitely use a single callable/HTTP function there, so that you can control the flow synchronously. If it's a email/password user, you can also handle the user creation in the Cloud Function.